# Flutter: I want to save my video to cache

Tags: flutter

I have a video. I want to save this video to my cache. and I want to watch this video from cache. if I use flutter_cache_manager. Can I do it ?

Comment: Yes, you can use that package to cache video files.

Comment: videoyu kaydediyorum şuanda bu şekilde.     "/data/user/0/com.example.flutter_cache_manager/cache/libCachedImageData/fc65e4a0-0fb7-11eb-a1ed-53020f3249ad.file"   . cacheden de çekiyrum şuanda fakat bunu nasıl mp4' çevireceğim?